# Grouping animations on different properties

Tags: qt, animation, qml

I have a generic `QtObject` in QML that I want to animated properties of, and I want to start/stop them all together. I wrote the following code, but Qt Creator errors: `qrc:/DummyData.qml:11 Cannot assign to non-existent default property`

...where line 11 is the one with `ParallelAnimation {`.

```
import QtQuick 2.5

QtObject {
  property real windowFrontLeftOpenPct:  0.0
  property real windowFrontRightOpenPct: 0.0
  property real windowRearLeftOpenPct:   0.0
  property real windowRearRightOpenPct:  0.0

  property bool windowAnimationsActive: false

  ParallelAnimation {
    running: windowAnimationsActive

    SequentialAnimation on windowFrontLeftOpenPct {
      loops: Animation.Infinite
      NumberAnimation { from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
      NumberAnimation { from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
    }
    SequentialAnimation on windowFrontRightOpenPct {
      loops: Animation.Infinite
      NumberAnimation { from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
      NumberAnimation { from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
    }
    SequentialAnimation on windowRearLeftOpenPct {
      loops: Animation.Infinite
      NumberAnimation { from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
      NumberAnimation { from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
    }
    SequentialAnimation on windowRearRightOpenPct {
      loops: Animation.Infinite
      NumberAnimation { from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
      NumberAnimation { from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
    }
  }
}
```

Can I not mix different target properties in a single parallel animation?

---

<sup>Note: a workaround in this case is to remove the `ParallelAnimation` wrapper and apply `running:windowAnimationsActive` to each of the SequentialAnimations. However, this is not a generic solution, I think, as it does not allow me to easily pause and resume many animations via a single parent wrapper.</sup>

Comment: The `QtObject` has no default property. When you declare child items in visual elements in QML, they are added into the special default property of an `Item`. `QtObject has none. You'll have to be explicit about the instantiation of the child `ParallelAnimation` - put it into a custom named property. AFAIK, this problem has nothing to do with animations. A minimum test case is a `QtObject` that you create *any* QML sub-object in: `QtObject { QtObject {} }`.

Comment: @KubaOber This sounds reasonable. May I ask why you commented instead of answering?

Comment: I usually answer only if I have the time to run some code to make sure I'm not full of it :) I've also not written any QML in the recent months, so I'm a bit rusty in that area. Better safe than sorry, and I hate to be misleading in an answer. Comments are fair game, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store it in custom property:

```
QtObject {
    id: windowPositions
    property real windowFrontLeftOpenPct:  0.0
    property real windowFrontRightOpenPct: 0.0
    property real windowRearLeftOpenPct:   0.0
    property real windowRearRightOpenPct:  0.0

    property bool windowAnimationsActive: false

    property ParallelAnimation windowAnimations: ParallelAnimation {
        running: windowAnimationsActive

        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowFrontLeftOpenPct"; from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowFrontLeftOpenPct"; from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
        }
        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowFrontRightOpenPct"; from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowFrontRightOpenPct"; from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
        }
        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowRearLeftOpenPct"; from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowRearLeftOpenPct"; from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
        }
        SequentialAnimation {
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowRearRightOpenPct"; from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions; property: "windowRearRightOpenPct"; from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you cannot use the 'on property' syntax that way. Yo need to specify by target and name. And you could use `properties` to change many with one Animation:

```
QtObject {
    id: windowPositions
    property real windowFrontLeftOpenPct:  0.0
    property real windowFrontRightOpenPct: 0.0
    property real windowRearLeftOpenPct:   0.0
    property real windowRearRightOpenPct:  0.0

    property bool running: false

    property SequentialAnimation windowAnimations: SequentialAnimation {
            running: windowPositions.running
            loops: Animation.Infinite

            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions;
                properties: "windowFrontLeftOpenPct,windowFrontRightOpenPct,windowRearLeftOpenPct,windowRearRightOpenPct";
                from:0; to:1; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
            NumberAnimation { target: windowPositions;
                properties: "windowFrontLeftOpenPct,windowFrontRightOpenPct,windowRearLeftOpenPct,windowRearRightOpenPct";
                from:1; to:0; duration:2000; easing.type:Easing.InOutSine }
    }
}
```

That is just a concept, because creating 4 same properties for same one value is useless as useless is creating the QtObject here, and if you need it somewhere I would call it a bad design.